# Create Vector from LookUp-Table / CSV-File in R

Tags: r, csv, vector, intersect

I have a CSV-file, where two columns contain one or more integers per cell.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","a","b"), 
y=c("datatype 1","datatype 1","datatype 2", "datatype 2"), 
z=c("2,3", "1,2","1,2,3,4,5", "3"))

names(df) <- c("hypothesis", "type", "mass") 

> df
  hypothesis       type      mass
1          a datatype 1       2,3
2          b datatype 1       1,2
3          a datatype 2 1,2,3,4,5
4          b datatype 2         3
```

I want to extract those integers from the .csv as vectors and assign them to variables `x` (datatype 1, hypothesis a) and `y` (datatype 2, hypothesis a) in my code.

Right now, I'm using `subset` to filter the table by "datatype" (column 2) and `which`("hypothesis"/column 1) to get the corresponding "mass" values I need. In the next step I want to use `intersect` to find out, which elements are shared by `x` and `y` variables.

My question is, how can I get a .csv cell content like "1,2,3" into a `vector`, to which the `intersect` function is applicable?

When I just call the cell, I get `typeof` `integer` and when `intersect` is applied, the result is `character(0)`. When I manually assign `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5); y <- c(2,3)` the result is - as it should be - `2 3`

Comment: Pictures are not code or data unless it's image processing-related. Please try to respect the folks who answer on the site and follow the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example that were shown in the links presented to you when you posted a question in the R tag. The use of images for data or code is now at almost epidemic proportions in the R tag.

Comment: My apologies, I edited the post, I hope it is replicable and up to standards now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `split` the 'mass' by the 'type', split the string using `strsplit`, `unlist`, convert to `numeric`, get the `unique` elements and apply `intersect` to find the elements that are common across the `list` elements

```
lst <- setNames(lapply(split(df$mass, df$type), function(x) 
       sort(unique(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ",")))))), c("x", "y"))

Reduce(intersect, lst)
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. I tried part of your suggested code:    my data looks like this: `> x
[[1]]
[1] 2,3
Levels:  1 1,2 1,2,3,4,5 2 2,3 2,3,4,5 3 3,4,5 4 5` i used your code: `a <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ",")))` and the result is: `> a
[1] 6` . Do I need to assign the column in my dataframe a different data type? I really do just need a vector of the elements, I would like to apply the intersect in a different step (in the function I am currently writing, I have 4 variables that need to be intersected with each other). Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Ezra If you need 4 variables to be intersect, it is better to keep it as a `list` (as I showed and then use `Reduce` instead of creating individual objects in the global environment

Comment: @Ezra Regarding your object `x`, is it a `list` or `vector` ?  If it is a `list`, then `strsplit(as.character(unlist(x)), ",")`

Comment: thank you. My mistake - apparantly - was the `as.character`! I just wrote as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))).